# Trying to PXE Install 14.04 with local mirror, but install keeps reaching out to canonical IPs

Tags: server, system-installation, software-sources, pxe, apt-mirror

I have a local mirror setup with apt-mirror, my `/etc/apt/mirror.list` file is included at the bottom of this post.

Even though I have all of the repo's I can think of defined for some reason my VMs are still trying to reach out to canonicals IPs during installation for some packages.

I haven't resorted to firing up wireshark yet, as i wanted to see if the community could provide insight before i start digging through logs.

with a block all "wan" traffic in place, my pxe installation halts and I can see denials to IPs like `91.189.88.153:80`.

Can anyone look at my mirror.list and tell me what packages might be missing?

If you are curious my mirror for now is open to the web at https://mirror.devita.co, once this issue is resolved i plan on closing it down.

### mirror.list

```
#trusty-updates
deb-amd64 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer  universe universe/debian-installer multiverse multiverse/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer  universe universe/debian-installer multiverse multiverse/debian-installer
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
#trusty
deb-amd64 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer  universe universe/debian-installer multiverse multiverse/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer  universe universe/debian-installer multiverse multiverse/debian-installer
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse

#trusty-backports
deb-amd64 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer  universe universe/debian-installer multiverse multiverse/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer  universe universe/debian-installer multiverse multiverse/debian-installer
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

#trusty-security
deb-amd64 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-security main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer  universe universe/debian-installer multiverse multiverse/debian-installer
deb-i386 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-security main main/debian-installer restricted restricted/debian-installer  universe universe/debian-installer multiverse multiverse/debian-installer
deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://deb.theforeman.org/ trusty 1.6
deb http://deb.theforeman.org/ plugins 1.6
deb http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.2/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb-src http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.2/ubuntu/ trusty main
deb http://packages.elasticsearch.org/logstashforwarder/debian stable main

clean http://packages.elasticsearch.org
clean http://deb.theforeman.org
clean http://repo.zabbix.com
clean http://mirrors.digitalocean.com
```

Comment: Have you defined the mirror selected for installation by preseeding?

Comment: yes i have, i can see hits to my nginx server at my mirror url, but for some reason i see 3 or 4 reachouts to that external IP. I included a link to my mirror via https in the question.

Comment: That maybe because the `security.ubuntu.com` mirror is also used by the installer.

Comment: I think thats it!, now the next question is how to get that overridden in my pxe config.. im using Foreman default preseed. It looks like this: https://gist.github.com/mikedevita/9a455b6c08f8590eb7a1

Comment: You can use these keys for that: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8360653/

Comment: Thanks, i think thats it, post this as an answer so i can give you credits.

Comment: Better test it out. Those keys are commented out in my preseed file, and I didn't notice any attempts for Canonical IPs.

Comment: that was it, now im only getting hits for NTP, thats next on my list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Canonical IPs you see maybe for `security.ubuntu.com`. You can set the location for this mirror using these preseed keys:

```
d-i apt-setup/security_protocol string http
d-i apt-setup/security_host string security.ubuntu.com
d-i apt-setup/security_path string /ubuntu
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it. Im using foreman to provision my hosts and the preseed template doesn't include these by default. I had to modify it to include these three lines alone with changing them to `<%= @preseed_server %>` and `<%= preseed_path %>` respectively.

Comment: @gorelative I don't know what a Foreman template is, but you could file a bug or submit a patch for them.

Comment: Its an ENC for doing automated VM provisioning via PXE using puppet.. http://theforeman.org, ill take it up with them. Thanks again Muru.